# How to add more processes and nodes to a running MPI job through SLURM?

Tags: mpi, hpc, slurm

In my university cluster, resources are scarce. Sometimes I run the program on fewer nodes. I want to know if there is a possibility of adding more nodes as more nodes become available.

My program is a simple master-slave program and I run it with

```
mpirun --np <num of processes> ./program
```

Essentially the question is if the program is started with say 64 processes, can 32 processes be added later without terminating the program.

Thank you.

Regards,

Harsh M

Comment: before addressing the SLURM issue, you have to make sure your app has a way to be notified more resources are available to be used. I am sure there are ways to achieve it, but this is not something MPI is "natively" designed for.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Are you implying that my program needs to have some workers register where workers can register on the fly? I don't know how to do that, But I will look for it. The second question is to say I modified my program to include such functionality; how will I add more nodes to running MPI through SLURM?

Comment: This is correct! When you are there, check https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#job_size for the SLURM side of the story